# About The Order of an Integer

Tags: number-theory, primitive-roots

[In this bolg](http://mathcenter.oxford.emory.edu/site/math125/orderOfAnInteger/) It says
$x=ord_{n}b$ and $ord_n = $ the least positive integer x such that $b^x\equiv $ 1 (mod  n)
and below it says $b^x\equiv $ 1 (mod  n) if and only if $ord_{n}b$ | x and then it gives proof for that. Aren't these values already equal? so of course they divide each other or I'm missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be lots of exponents that cause $b^x \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.  The order is the *least positive* of these.

For instance,

$$2^3 \equiv 2^6 \equiv 2^{15} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

and note that $3$ divides each of $6$ and $15.$

Comment: Oh I completely missed this point. Thanks!!